# jQuery dialog load content

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-dialog

```
<div id="modal" style="display: none;">loading...</div>
<a href="#" class="ajax">click me</a>
```

```js
$('.ajax').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#modal').dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: 100,
                height: 100
            });
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#modal').html('new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value ');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wrd7xr5m/

How can I use the same dialog in `success` with restore width\height with new content? In real project I use this:

```
$('#modal').html(data)
```

Comment: Is what do you want, only change the witdh and height of dialog? Please, explain better what you are trying to achive.

Comment: Or just remove it from plugin initialization: `$('#modal').dialog({
                modal: true});` ???

Comment: If you've reached `success` then your data is loaded in the modal and you can just use it later on with `$('#modal').dialog();`. The question is kinda vague.. please clarify how and where you want to use the same dialog..

Comment: set `var modalConfig = {
                modal: true,
                width: 100,
                height: 100
            }` and use `modalConfig` that everywhere..

Comment: here is example https://jsfiddle.net/9rqdqo0c/ but i can't center dialod in success

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same jquery object `$('#modal')`. You just need to set again the configuration values you need by calling `dialog` method.

```
 $('#modal').dialog( "option", "width", 500 )
        .dialog( "option", "height", 300 )
        .html('new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value new value ');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wrd7xr5m/2/

Answer (score 1):

why not use a Function?

```
 $('.ajax').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/',
            beforeSend: openDialog(),
            success: openDialog({width:600px})
        });
        return false;
    });

   function openDialog(setting){
            var defaultSetting = { 
                modal:true, 
                height: 400, 
                width: 450
            }
            //if you have any custom setting then pass object
            if(setting!=undefined)
               $.extend(defaultSetting ,setting);

            var myDialog= $('#modal').dialog(defaultSetting);
}
```

Comment: That is a good solution @Charly. I like how you dealt with setting argument using `$.extend`. Learned a new thing today!

Comment: Thanks, but @ParthTrivedi added the $.extend part to my answer. Click on "edited Jan 15 at 13:14" to see my simplified and more readable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another good way to do it would be to get a object reference to the `dialog` and then use it in anywhere in your code. You can override/define attribute values using the `.dialog("option", "<attribute>", <value>);` notation.

**For example:**

`myDialogObject.dialog("option", "position", {my:"left top", at:"left bottom", of:window});`

---

### Using object reference

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //1. Initialize the dialog with 'autoOpen' attribute set to false.
    var myDialogObj = $('#modal').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 100,
        height: 100
    });

    //2. Make your async call.
    $('.ajax').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/',
            beforeSend: function() {
                //open the dialog using object reference.
                myDialogObj.dialog('open');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                myDialogObj.html('new value for the dialog, could also have a page content loaded dynamically using the ".load(url,successCallback(){})" function.');
                //set the height and width as per your custom requirement or leave it, if you want auto adjustments.
                myDialogObj.dialog("option", "width", 340);
                myDialogObj.dialog("option", "height", 200);
                //open the dialog using object reference.
                myDialogObj.dialog('open');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Try the fiddle [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/jack4dev/e1qu020k/9/).

> References:

- https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog